# does exporting two times in mef point to the same object

Tags: .net, mef

```
[Export]
[Export(typeof(IClass))
public Class : IClass
```

Can I expect the same singleton when I use constructor injection for Class and IClass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, regardless of the number of exports, the `CreationPolicy.Shared` is specified per type, which means as the actual runtime type resultant of `Export` and `Export(typeof(IClass))`. You can see this with an example:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}

[Export]
[Export(typeof(IMyClass))]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  private static int count;

  public MyClass()
  {
    count++;
    Name = "Instance " + count;
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}

var container = new CompositionContainer(
  new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

var instance1 = container.GetExportedValue<MyClass>();
var instance2 = container.GetExportedValue<IMyClass>();

// should be true.
bool referenceEquals = object.ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance2);

// should also be true.
bool nameEquals = instance1.Name == instance2.Name;
```